# Live data stream from Logitech webcam c110

Tags: webcam, logitech, video-streaming

I wanted to stream live data of my logitech c110 webcam using my Ubuntu machine. How can I do this?

After little bit of tweaking I came to know that I have to install motion. I tried `sudo apt-get install motion` but that is not working.

Can anyone please tell me how to do this? My Ubuntu is behind a proxy (it is in the office).

Answer (score 0):

Install ffserver to stream over HTTP:

```
apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Configuration:

```
Port 8090
BindAddress YOUR_IP_ADDRESS
MaxHTTPConnections 30
MaxClients 20
MaxBandwidth 2000
CustomLog -

<Feed cam1.ffm>
File /tmp/cam1.ffm
FileMaxSize 10000K
ACL allow 12.34.56.78
</Feed>

#-----
# Windows Media Player
#-----
<Stream cam1.asf>
Feed cam1.ffm
Format asf
VideoCodec msmpeg4v2
VideoFrameRate 15
VideoSize vga
VideoBitRate 320
VideoBufferSize 40
VideoGopSize 15
NoAudio StartSendOnKey
</Stream>

<Stream stat.html>
Format status
ACL allow 12.34.56.78
</Stream>
```

Assuming your webcam is a Video4Linux device at /dev/video0, give the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 YOUR_IP_ADDRESS/cam1.ffm
```

At this point, FFMpeg will begin capturing video from your camera. It'll do the transcoding to the proper format locally and send that off to your server.
Leave it to encode for about half a minute and then hit your server's stream URL using a Pideo Player, in this URL: YOUR_IP_ADDRESS/cam1.asf The player will buffer for a bit and your video will start playing.

You're done.

Comment: My company's proxy is blocking to connect to ubuntu archive. is there any alternative to achieve this under proxy?

Comment: Ask your IT Department, to unblock.